# XSLT 1.0 find row containing a specific value in first cell, then read only subsequent rows after that

Tags: xml, xslt, foreach, xslt-1.0

I am trying to write XSLT code which begins reading rows after it has identified the ‘real header’ row: the ‘real header’ is the row which contains the word “Template name” in its first column.

Here’s what makes it XML tricky (because not every incoming XML will look the same):
-   The incoming XML file can contain any small, variable number of meta-header rows (like the first one in the XML example below); and,
-   The incoming XML file can contain any small, variable number of “white-space” rows

Which means that the ‘real header’ could vary in position anywhere from the 3rd row up to the 10th (depending, again, on the number of ‘meta-header’ and ‘whitespace’ rows).

Here’s a snippet of what I have for XSLT code (doesn’t quite work):

```
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <Payments>
      <xsl:if test="contains(column1, 'Template')" />
      <xsl:for-each select="data/row[position()&gt;1 and position()&lt;last()]">
        <Record>
...
```

The XML can look something like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
<row>
  <t1>HeaderOne</t1>
  <t2>(All)</t2>
  <t3></t3>
  <t4></t4>
  <t5></t5>
</row>
<row>
  <t1></t1>
  <t2></t2>
  <t3></t3>
  <t4></t4>
  <t5></t5>
</row>
<row>
  <t1>Template name</t1>
  <t2>Currency<t2>
  <t3>Sum of Currency Amount</t3>
  <t4>Sum of Settlement Amount- always USD</t4>
  <t5>Reference</t5>
</row>
<row>
  <t1>Jerry Smith</t1>
  <t2>CAD</t2>
  <t3>232.00</t3>
  <t4>176.00</t4>
  <t5>ABCHoldings</t5>
</row>
```

The resulting transformation should start picking up on the row which starts with “Jerry Smith”

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for the `following-sibling` axis. Just do this...

```
<xsl:for-each select="root/row[t1 = 'Template name']/following-sibling::row">
```

Comment: Thanks! What if the incoming file is actually a CSV, how would this logic be different?

Comment: It would be very different. as XSLT is primarily designed to work with an XML file as the primary document. You'd have to upgrade to XSLT 2.0 at the very least if you wanted to process a CSV. That would be a whole new question though...